# An error was thrown in afterAll [object ErrorEvent] when using path to module in require.context()

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-cli, karma-jasmine

I am getting a really strange error in my Angular app when I execute `ng test` with this config:

```js
const context: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/); // all modules
const contextModule1: any = require.context('./app/modules/abc-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/); // ABC module only
const contextModule2: any = require.context('./app/modules/def-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/); // DEF module only
```

Running all (300+) tests is successful:

```js
context.keys().map(context); // path: './'
```

But running just the tests in one of the modules fails:

```js
context.keys().map(contextModule1); // path: './app/modules/abc-module'
```

Both (correct) paths fail with:

> An error was thrown in afterAll [object ErrorEvent]

This seems completely unrelated. Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the test.ts config to this solved it:

```
// const context: any = require.context('./', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
// const context: any = require.context('./app/modules/abc-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);
const context: any = require.context('./app/modules/def-module', true, /\.spec\.ts$/);

context.keys().map(context);
```

It has to be the same variable: `context`. Changing the variable in `map()` seems to cause the error. Instead, I have to use comments to be able to switch between the three paths.

I am aware, that require.context's arguments must be static and not be variables, but having multiple require.context() saved in different variables should not contradict with that - so I don't have an explanation for the error.